# Time Out error trying on send request using a Node Express app

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning through a tutorial to  create a form that sends data to my local server and I'm getting a time out error. It's my first time working on post requests using a node.js express application and I'm stuck.

This is the handlebars code:

```
form method="POST" action="send">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServerUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend3">@</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServerUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend3" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please choose a username.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer03">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServer03" placeholder="City" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid city.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer04">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServer04" placeholder="State" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid state.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer05">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServer05" placeholder="Zip" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid zip.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input is-invalid" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck3" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck3">
        Agree to terms and conditions
      </label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        You must agree before submitting.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

This is the entry point code:

```
onst express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const exphbs = require ('express-handlebars');
const nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');
const path = require ('path');

const app = express ();


//View Engine Setup
app.engine ('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set ('view engine', 'handlebars');

//Static Folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Body Parser Middleware

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//route

app.get ('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('contact', {layout:false})
});

//post route for submission
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen (3000,() => console.log ('Server started...'));
```

All I'm getting on my server is: {} when I try to submit.

Comment: In your `app.post('/send')` you didn't send any response, you did just console.log that's why you are getting timeout error. you should send some response to the client using `res.render` or `res.send`

Comment: It's logging an empty array on my local server...

Comment: Please try adding `name` attribute for all the input fields in the form

Comment: According to this tutorial: {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF9g1825mwk}, at 19:26, it should be logging the content of the input fields.

Comment: It worked! Why does it need the "name" attribute? I need to understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you send a form value to the server, always add `name` attribute to your input fields. Otherwise you won't get the request parameters (`req.body`) in the server side.

`name` attribute serves as a JSON property in your case. If you don't provide `name` attribute, the JSON won't get updated with the field values.

Take some time to read this tutorial: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: I'm still trying to understand forms in the big picture.... so sorry to ask another question, but in case of that form, what would be the best way to handle server side validation? I don't know any other language other than JS.

Comment: You can make an if statement to check whether the `req.body` has value or not, if it doesn't have any value, you can respond with an error message like `res.send('Invalid parameters');`